# Probability, without replacement

Tags: probability

An urn contains 11 balls, of which 4 are white. Three players $A$, $B$, and $C$, successively draw from the urn. $A$ first, then $B$, then $C$, then $A$ again, and so on. The winner is the first one to draw a white ball. Find the probability of winning for each player, assuming the balls that are withdrawn are not replaced.

Find $\mathbf{P}(A \text{ wins})$
Find $\mathbf{P}(B \text{ wins})$
Find $\mathbf{P}(C \text{ wins})$

I have completed the same problem with replacement of the marbles. I do not know how to start without replacement.

Comment: Probability that the first white ball is 1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th 7th 8th? Then add up

Answer (score 1):

For A to win, the first white ball could occur at position $1$, $4$, $7$ (and $11$ to have the first white is not possible), that is $$\frac{A_4^1A_{10}^{10} + A_{7}^{3}A_4^1A_7^7+A_7^6A_4^1A_4^4}{A_{11}^{11}}$$

Similar for B and C.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $4$ white and $7$ red balls in the box. Then:
$$P(A)=P(W_A)+P(R_AR_BR_CW_A)+P(R_AR_BR_CR_AR_BR_CW_A)=\frac{4}{11}+\frac{7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{11\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 8}+\frac{7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 4}{11\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5}\approx 0.4818.$$
Similarly for $P(B), P(C)$.

Comment: I did exactly as you did for P(A) and got .47474, but this answer is showing as incorrect.

Comment: I corrected the typo.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.